# How to know if the picture preview is discarded (or the picture is a retake)

Tags: android

I start the camera Intent from my app. Once picture is taken, 2 options are given: Accept or discard.
Is there a way to know when the picture is discarded (or when the picture is taken again in the same intent)? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can know if the user did not take a picture via a `resultCode` of `RESULT_CANCELED` in `onActivityResult()`.

You cannot determine what the user did inside of the third-party camera activity, though, such as "when the picture is taken again in the same intent".

Comment: @Snake: It's not your app -- it's the camera app. It's like saying that you want to know where the user all visits inside of some third-party maps app. If you want to know precisely what the user is doing with the camera, use `android.hardware.Camera` yourself.